# Forcing compatibility mode IE not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

I need to display a webpage in compatibility mode. I've tried the following tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

But this only works if I have compatibility mode ON. With compatibility mode ON, the above tag allows me to change which version of IE the document should be displayed in. With compatibility mode OFF, the above tag has no affect.

Shouldn't this work with compatibility mode OFF?

My situation: Developing website that looks perfect when viewed in IE10/11 with compatibility mode ON. With it OFF it looks bad. Fixing it so that it runs without compatibility mode is not an option. What I need is to force compatibility mode ON for any user that views the site, so that they do not need to manually turn it on. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well if it only works perfectly when you have compatibility ON in those browsers, you might need to set the content type to IE9 or IE8?

Comment: It doesn't matter what content type I set it to if compatibility mode is OFF. The tag is only having an impact if compatibility mode has already been manually turned ON.

Answer (score 2):

**Use:**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

You should use IE=edge to tell Internet Explorer to use the highest mode available.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'll probably use Edge *if* I can get the tag to work with compatibility mode OFF. Currently setting it to Edge has no affect.

Comment: Make sure:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

is the first <meta> tag on your page, otherwise IE may not respect it.

Comment: Yes, I have it as the first tag after the <head> tag. Is it possible that this setting is being overridden at the server level?

Comment: What server side language do you use ?

Comment: Not sure, big company and I have limited access...but I now know that its not the server. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `X-UA-Compatible` is not working is because I am using IE11. IE8 will turn compatibility mode on automatically, and then as a developer you can set the content mode. But IE 10/11 require compatibility mode to be set on manually before you can begin controlling emulation via meta tags.